# Drop down to hide rows based on a dropdown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

In Google Sheets I want to hide rows *5 to 31* when my drop down in `R4` says **BLS**, and show those cells if `R4` is **blank** or says **ALS**.

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Shee1");
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var R4 = sh.getRange("R4").getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i < vA.length; i++) {
    var row = i + 1;
    switch (R4) {
      case "BLS":
        if (row >= 5 && row <= 31) {
          sh.hideRows(row);
        }
        break;
      case "ALS":
        if (row >= 4 && row <= 32) {
          sh.showRows(row);
        }
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried this, which points to 2 different macros that I recorded but it makes the screen go crazy and jumps around whenever something else is edited:

```
function onEdit(){ 
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R4').getValue() == "BLS") BLS(); // Launches the script
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R4').getValue() == "ALS") ALS(); // Launches the script
}
```

Comment: Can you show us [what have you done and what have you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so far please?

Comment: this is the most recent attempt. :      function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Shee1");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var R4=sh.getRange("R4").getValue();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    var row=i+1;
    switch(R4)
    {
     case 'BLS':
        if(row>=5 && row<=31){sh.hideRows(row);} 
      
      
        break;
      case 'ALS':
        if(row>=4 && row<=32){sh.showRows(row);}
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
}

Comment: I have also tried this which points to 2 different macros that I recorded but it makes the screen go crazy and jumps around whenever something else is edited                 function onEdit(){
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R4').getValue() == "BLS")
  BLS(); // Launches the script
 if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('R4').getValue() == "ALS"){ 
  ALS(); // Launches the script 
  }
}

Comment: Please put the code into the provided answer area and select just the code and press control k. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: You need to use code guards to only execute your `BLS()` or `ALS()` functions **if the edited cell** was your "trigger cell", R4. Otherwise you probably don't want to activate those functions. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51716221/9337071) about how you can add code guards to an edit-triggered function.

Comment: @tehhowch see my edited code. Not sure if I did the coded guards right or at all. Like I said really new to this. Both macros run but keep running every time sheet is edited

Comment: Scott, I had seen your edited code when I wrote that comment. Please refer to the bold portion of my previous comment for the missing bit in your current guards, and then re-read the answer I linked.

Comment: I edited code again. I'm still not sure if I am getting it. Not working at all now

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");           // Enter sheet name
var row = s.getRange('R:R').getValues(); 
// Enter column letter that has the      text "hide" and  "unhide"

s.showRows(1, s.getMaxRows());
for(var i=0; i< row.length; i++){ if(row[i] == 'hide') { s.hideRows(i+1, 27); } 
else if(row[i] == 'unhide'){ s.unhideRow(ss.getDataRange()); } 
}
}
```

Comment: Used conditional formatting to solve my issue. Works good put this formula in a cell: =if($R$4="BLS","hide","unhide").