# Specify Google Sheet tab in script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to get a script to only look at a specific tab/sheet when someone edits  specific columns to send an automated email notification. It is however sending email notifications for any edits on all tabs. How do can I specify the sheet: "CT - Training"

```
function sendNotification() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('CT - Training');
    //Get Active cell
    var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
    var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
    var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
    //Define Notification Details
    var recipients = "email@email.email";
    var subject = "Update to "+ss.getName();
    var body = ss.getName() + "has been updated.  Visit " + ss.getUrl() + " to view the changes.";
    //Check to see if column is A or B to trigger
    if (cellcol == 17);
      //Check to see if column is A or B to trigger
      if (cellcol == 20);
      {
        //Send the Email
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
      }
    //End sendNotification
 }
```

Comment: There is no `activeSpreadsheet` property, so it may be that your function is ignoring line 3.  It should build from line 2:  `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('CT - Training');`.

Comment: Review my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711360/my-onedit-function-keeps-deleting-my-data/51716221#51716221 also note that `cellcol` cannot be both 17 and 20, so this function cannot send any emails as written.